# Cannot determine sudo password!

Tags: command-line, sudo, password

When I installed Ubuntu Studio 19.10, I didn't add password for login. Now anytime I try to do something with the terminal it asks for my sudo password but of course I have no way of finding out what that is, since: 
a) GRUB does not appear for me at all when I boot system
b) I cannot open etc/sudoers

Totally new user...have installed Ubuntu in light of world events, covid and love for open source community. 
THANK YOU!

Comment: a) [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Comment: Reset admin password https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed it very recently, i could suggest you to reinstall it(formatting and install again) or try to enter to the instalation and "repair" your actual version.

If you do this, try to add a password to the user, one easy for you to remmember, so you can have it easily(and dont have this problem again)

About the GRUB, i cant help you. I have a grub because i installed linux having windows in another partition.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Start your machine in recovery mode -> Resume to normal boot. You should get a prompt with root. Follow the steps below:**

```
root@demo:~$ mount -o remount,rw /

root@demo:~$ passwd yourusername
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully

root@demo:~$ reboot
```

**2. You can use chroot. Start your machine with Live CD/DVD/USB**

Start a terminal and mount your root disk as per the following steps below

**Check which is your root disk? :**

```
ubuntu@demo:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 083E1E28-FEE5-4BF0-B7CE-84520FB93B9D

Disposit.     Start     Final  Sectores  Size Tipo
/dev/sda1      2048    391167    389120  190M EFI System
/dev/sda2    391168  58660699  58269532 27,8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  58660864 234440703 175779840 83,8G Linux filesystem
```

**In this case my root disk is /dev/sda2**

```
ubuntu@demo:~$ mkdir disk
ubuntu@demo:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 disk
```

**You can check the files to ensure it's the root partition**

```
ubuntu@demo:~$ sudo ls disk 
bin    dev    home        lib     media  proc  sbin  sys  var
boot   initrd.img      lib64      mnt    root  snap  tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  etc    initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt    run   srv   usr  vmlinuz.old

ubuntu@demo:~$ sudo chroot disk
```

**Enter "passwd" command followed by your username**

```
root@demo_chroot:~$ passwd yourusername
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

**Exit from chroot**

```
root@demo_chroot:~$ exit
```

**Finish unmounting and reboot**

```
ubuntu@demo:~$ sudo umount disk
ubuntu@demo:~$ reboot
```